# Proof Graph Strongly connected component

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

if $P(x, y)$ is the path predicate of any directed graph, then the predicate 
$P(x, y)\wedge P(y, x)$ is an equivalence relation. The equivalence classes of this relation are called strongly connected components. Prove that a graph has no strongly connected components with more than one element if and only if it has no directed cycle with more than one node.

I don't understand the part Prove that a graph has no strongly connected components with more than one element if and only if it has no directed cycle with more than one node.

if it's an equivalence class then it has equivalence classes so how can it have no strongly connected components ?

Comment: It must have strongly connected components, but they might have only one element each.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Ohh thanks I think I get it, What's the best way to prove it. I thought about induction but I couldn't do it that way.

Comment: $P(x,y)$ means there is a path from $x$ to $y$. $P(y,x)$ means there is path from $y$ to $x$. Now what do you get when you put those two paths together?